# Как узнать версию jdbc на уже работающем linux сервере?

Tags: jdbc, shell, java, linux

Попал в затруднительное положение. Необходимо узнать версию jdbc на уже работающем linux сервере. Есть доступ к консоли. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 2):

А база-то какая?

Версию java через вызов

```
java --version
```

Версию базы через вызовы

```
DriverManager.getDataBaseProductName
DriverManager.getDataBaseProductVersion
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Драйвер JDBC для MySQL - libmysql-java
Драйвер JDBC для Sybase - libjtds-java
Драйвер JDBC для PostgreSQL - libpg-java
```

Версию (в debian-based дистрибутивах) можно узнать так:

```
$ dpkg -s libmysql-java
```

Comment: Тех поддержка sybase :
Also, SQL Anywhere does not support the use of the jTDS driver. Only jConnect and the SAJDBC driver are supported.